# RestKit 0.10.0 with foursquare API's not retrieving the response when using blocks

Tags: ios, json, restkit, objective-c-blocks, foursquare

Um beginner with RestKit, first example for me was on foursquare API's and I've used RestKit with Blocks not delegates.

I want to retrive the name's of venues,this is the JSON response
[image]

and this is my code:

// App Delegate.m

```
    RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURLString:@"https://api.Foursquare.com/v2"];
RKManagedObjectStore *objectStore = [RKManagedObjectStore objectStoreWithStoreFilename:@"Venue.sqlite"];
objectManager.objectStore = objectStore;
objectManager.serializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON;
RKManagedObjectMapping *venueMapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Venue class] inManagedObjectStore:objectStore];

[venueMapping mapKeyPath:@"id" toAttribute:@"id"];
[venueMapping mapKeyPath:@"name" toAttribute:@"name"];
venueMapping.primaryKeyAttribute = @"id";

[objectManager.mappingProvider setMapping:venueMapping forKeyPath:@"response.venue"];
```

then in myViewController.m

```
-(void)loadVenues{

// When caling loadObjectsAtResourcePath method it specify RKObjectLoader which is the actual request.
// within these block you can take more options to controll the request.


[[RKObjectManager sharedManager]loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"/venues/40a55d80f964a52020f31ee3?oauth_token=FNQPN5P5EKLJ5IQ44TMWO00I3W033M0Y1TKINW2OTF2VIOTP&v=20130512" usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader* loader)
{
    loader.objectMapping = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider objectMappingForClass:[Venue class]];
    loader.onDidLoadObject = ^(NSArray *objects)
    {
        NSLog(@"onDidLoadObject Blocks");
        self.data = objects;
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    };
}
 ];
```

}

and the app is entering the block of onDidLoadObject but every time the array is empty !!
even when I test the link on browser it comes with data.

When I debug the loader.URL it always come with these

https://api.Foursquare.com/v2/venues/40a55d80f964a52020f31ee3?v=20130512&oauth_token=FNQPN5P5EKLJ5IQ44TMWO00I3W033M0Y1TKINW2OTF2VIOTP -- https://api.Foursquare.com/v2 -- https://api.Foursquare.com/v2

I don't know why load.URL is wrong ?!

I think um calling the 4square API's with the wrong way, anyone can help ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-Put Your mapping as a class method to be accessed from all application classes, and done only once.

-change the Attribute "id" as it is reserved in Objective-C.

-add this to the block

```
[loader setObjectMapping:[RestKitMapping yourMapping]];
```

-then add this with your mapping code

```
[objectManager.mappingProvider setMapping:venueMapping forKeyPath:@"response.venue"];
```

-And use Delegates instead of blocks

Comment: There is a problem with Blocks in RestKit 0.10.0 you are right, it worked when I used delegates instead of Blocks.

Answer (score 0):

I've two concerns regarding the above code:

1- Apparently the above JSON response, lists just one Venue .. So KeyPath should be "response.venue" not "response.venues"

2- Where's the mapping for ID? .. which is the primary key that RestKit uses to insert into DB? You need to set the primary key mapping.

Comment: - There is a problem with Blocks in RestKit 0.10.0 you are right, it worked when I used delegates instead of Blocks.

- setObjectMapping:venueMapping instead of setMapping:venueMapping.

- To save in DB you have to tell the RestKit what is the primarykey in your data model and it should be correct, not like what I made id, If you don't made it will work and the response will come but no saving in coredate which is the most important point in RestKit :).
Thanks Shady & Goharey :)